# making trigger to prevent insert data

Tags: mysql, database

I have table name `booking`

```
id     room     name      date_IN      date_OUT
---    -----   -----     ---------     ---------
1       101     jack      2016-2-11     2016-2-13
2       102     mark      2016-2-11     2016-2-14
3       101     obama     2016-2-14     2016-2-17
4       101     suzy      2016-2-17   2016-2-18   everything is OK
```

id is primary key and auto increase Now ,i want to prevent  insert (5  , 101 , martin , 2016-2-15  , 2016-2-18 ) because the room (101) is reserved to suzy in that date....how i make trigger to all rooms ...please

Comment: I don't understand why you think you need a trigger. A simple query would normally suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** As OP said **there should no entry for 101 and reserved between date_IN and date_OUT...**:

Query should be:

```
<?php
$currentDate = '2016-2-12'; //date('Y-m-d');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM booking WHERE date_IN >= '$currentDate' AND date_OUT <= '$currentDate' ';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks vejani to answer ....But i dont need unique ,i want to repeat room depend on correct date

Comment: means on same date there must not two `101` id?

Comment: Not in same date ...mean that 101 may be repeat and it is reserved to certain date..mean 'hotel booking'

Comment: @ubuntu you can do it with coding

Comment: How can I do ...Vejani?

Comment: on same date there should no entry for `101`? @ubuntu

Comment: @ubuntu you can use query of MySQL